# bs4navwalker drop down not working

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-4, wp-nav-walker

in WordPress theme i use bs4navwalker and bootstrap4 to show menu everything is OK but when hover on parent menu the sub menu not showen

header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        <?php bloginfo('name');?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <?php
   wp_nav_menu([
     'theme_location'  => 'primary',
     'container'       => false,
     'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
     'depth'           => 2,
     'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
     'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
   ]);
   ?>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and functions.php:

```
<?php
require_once('bs4navwalker.php');
function theme_setup(){
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    register_nav_menus(array('primary'=>__('Primary Menu')
 ));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','theme_setup');
```

Comment: After you inspected to see what is going on with CSS? Do you have the correct JS files included?

Comment: my problem solved tanks wrong css and js is included its for bootstrap3 i put bootstrap4 cdn and its work